# Как дополнить скрипт для запоминания количества кристаллов?

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d

Я написал код для сбора кристаллов:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CrystallCollect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int crystallCount;
    private Text crystallConter;

    void Start()
    {
        crystallConter = GetComponent<Text>();
        crystallCount = 0;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        crystallConter.text = "" + crystallCount;
    }
}
```

После чего на персонажа добавил:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag.Equals("Crystall"))
        {
            CrystallCollect.crystallCount += 1;
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Как дополнить скрипт для запоминания количества кристаллов?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте метод для снятия кристаллов со счета (например для покупки или в качестве штрафа за смерть), сделайте Text crystallConter public, чтобы можно было из Unity перетаскивать объекты

```
public class CrystallCollect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int crystallCount;
    public Text crystallConter; 
    public int DeathWithdrawAmount = 10;//количество снятых кристаллов при смерти

    void Start()
    {
        crystallConter = GetComponent<Text>();
        crystallCount = 0;
    }

    public void Withdraw(int amount) //для снятия со счета
    {
        crystallCount -= amount
    }

    public void DeathPenalty() //вызывайте в скрипте персонажа при смерти
    {
        crystallCount -= DeathWithdrawAmount;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        crystallConter.text = "" + crystallCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, написать, а то я новичок мне тяжеловато понять. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @AisenApple, дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag.Equals("Crystall"))
        {
            CrystallCollect.crystallCount += 1;
    //Сохранение CrystallCollect.crystallCount
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("Crystall",CrystallCollect.crystallCount );
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

чтобы получить сохранённое сохранение нужно вставить куда то этот код в Start или куда  нибудь на ваше усмотрение

```
void Start()
{ 
  crystallCount = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("Crystall", 0);
}
```